# How to convert a large json response of a web service call into CSV in Python?

Tags: python

I have a web service which returns a very large JSON response. I want to parse it and convert it into a CSV format using Python. I have written a code to load json and convert it to CSV. However, for a large response it raises MemoryError. How can I load and convert response data using streaming?

Here is my code:

```py
import json
from pandas import json_normalize
re = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(re.text)
df = json_normalize(data)
df.to_csv(fileName, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is a sample of my JSON response:

```
[{"F1":"V1_1","F2":false,,"F3":120,"F4":"URL1","F5":{"F5_1":4,"F5_2":"A"}},
{"F1":"V2_1","F2":true,,"F3":450,"F4":"URL2","F5":{"F5_1":13,"F5_2":"B"}},
{"F1":"V3_1","F2":false,,"F3":312,"F4":"URL3","F5":{"F5_1":6,"F5_2":"C"}},
...
]
```

The MemoryError occurs in the `json.loads()` function (or the `response.json()` function if use it instead of `json.loads()`). Is there any idea how I can load and parse and convert such a big JSON response to a CSV file?

Comment: You should add the approaches that you have tried. Take a subset of your JSON and add it to here, so that the person who's answering, can see what are you trying to do here.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a sample of what the json data looks like?  Can you also show us exactly where you get the memory error and what it says?

Comment: I have added a sample of my json response. The MemoryError occur on json.loads() or response.json() function. @jawsem

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not making dataframe from only the `result` of the `response`, rather you are trying to push additional data with the result here. Try this and see if pandas can save this time.

```py
import pandas as pd

# this is a dummy URL for demonstration
url = "https://www.qnt.io/api/results?pID=gifgif&mID=54a309ae1c61be23aba0da62&key=54a309ac1c61be23aba0da3f"

response = requests.get(url)

# extract the relevant results from response
data = response.json()["results"]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: I run it. Still there is MemoryError on response.json(). My json is large file and is about 500 mb. The response.json() function load whole json response so the memory error occur.

Comment: Is there any new idea? I still have problem.